# HTML. Hide/Show a drop down menu depending on if an option is selected on another drop down menu

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I am trying to have originally just one drop down menu when a website loads. Lets say that drop down menu only has two options "A" and "B". If the user selects option "A" I want another drop menu then to appear on the website (just below the original). If the user selects option "B" I want a different menu to appear below the original. I am also using PHP to make things even more complicated. Can anyone guide me on how I can accomplish this?

Comment: javascript is your friend.  you could put those sub-menus in their own div's and use jquery to show and hide them.

Comment: Do these drop menu exist and just hide when document ready?and show/hide through choose "A" and "B"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify the two dropdowns with attribute `style="display:none"`.  In your javascript function you would have an event registered that based on the `SelectedIndex` you would choose which dropdown element to remove the `style="display:none"` from.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the work :

```
$("#drop").change(function() {
    if( $('#drop option:selected').val() == "A") {
        //Do what you want
    }
    else if ( $('#drop option:selected').val() == "B") {
        //Do what you want
    }
});
```

I don't know your level in js, if you need more explanations, please let me know.

Comment: My level of JS is non-existant. So what would the html portion of it be? Like the drop down menu containing A,B. Also in the if statements do I just put the html code for the other drop down menus?

Comment: As I mentioned I am also using php. Should the javascript function be echoed? Or does that go separately?

Answer (score 0):

[**Here's**](http://jsfiddle.net/8rr6k15x/2/) an example of manipulating the classes using native JavaScript. It could be cleaner, but it shows how you can check agains what classes exist in order to set CSS behaviour.

```
var cont = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
cont.className = 'row';


for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++ ) {
    var menuitem = cont.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
        menuitem.className = 'col';
    var internal = menuitem.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
        internal.appendChild(document.createTextNode('item'+ (i + 1)));

(internal.attachEvent) ?
    internal.attachEvent('onclick', function () {
        for (var j = 0; j < cont.children.length; j++){
            if (cont.children[j].className === 'col active') {
                cont.children[j].className = 'col';
            }
        };
        this.parentElement.className = 'col active';
    }) : 
    internal.addEventListener('click', function () {
        for (var j = 0; j < cont.children.length; j++){
            if (cont.children[j].className === 'col active') {
                cont.children[j].className = 'col';
            }
        };
        this.parentElement.className = 'col active';
    }, false);
};
```